# Angular HTTP Interceptor - $q.when - what does it do?

Tags: angularjs

While browsing Blogs and looked at the examples, inside Angular services I found right after the handling of HTTP status codes such lines of code:

`return response || $q.when(response);`

or

`return $q.reject(rejection);`

What does `$q.when` and `$q.reject(rejection)` actually mean and why the boolean "or" ?

Answer (score 2):

You can pass `$q.when` a promise or a type. If the passed parameter is not a promise - then then it will wrap it in a promise and call resolve. If is useful when you are dealing with an object that may or may not not be a promise.

The statement `response || $q.when(response)` means that it can return a value or a promise.

My guess is this - if the response is null it will return a promise - which will asynchronously resolve to the given value - which is null.

`$q.reject(reason)` returns a rejected promise with the reason it was rejected. It is basically a way of throwing an error as a promise that can be handled by a catch.

Answer (score 0):

Although it's hard to tell without the full code in the service, it looks as if the function will return the object "response" if it is [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) (meaning that it is not `null`, `undefined`, `false`, or `0`), and a [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) if response is falsy.  The promise will be resolved [when](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#when) response gets a value.

This probably isn't the BEST way for the service to go about doing this, but essentially the author wants you to test what the function returns.  If it's a promise, call [.then()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#the-promise-api) on it and handle the value there, otherwise handle the value immediately.